# Azure map layers available

Tags: azure-maps

The Azure base base map that displays with my map looks great but I don't see any of the streams or water basins labelled on the map.  Are there Azure map layers available to display this information?

Thanks,
Annette

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the data you are looking for isn't in the base map data. I recommend reporting this feedback on this site: https://feedback.azuremaps.com/ Click on the map where the streams/water basis are missing and press "Add comment". This will create a ticket with our data provider and an investigation will occur on their side to get this resolved in the future. When you send feedback it also creates a URL you can use to go back and check the status of your feedback.

Comment: We have a project where we used an ESRI web map and it included map layers such as Flood Zones Areas and TCAP Floodplains.  Is this type of information available in Azure maps?

Comment: Azure Maps doesn't provide flood zone area or floodplain data sets, but if you have access to them (many are open data), they can be used with Azure Maps.

Comment: Here is a WMS service from FEMA for the National Flood Hazard Layer https://hazards.fema.gov/nfhl/services/public/NFHLWMS/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Pass this into the Spatial IO OGC layer of Azure Maps: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=OGC%20map%20layer%20example